# PYGAME - How to read into en external class

Tags: python, pygame

Ok, i try to move player in the maze, to do this, the system must read in external file, i created a function in main class.
But I can't link this function with player for moving it.
I found nothing in here because all topics I have seen used only one file..

Here is the main file

```
import pygame as pg
from os import system, environ
from design import maze, constants as cst
from objects import player

system('clear')
environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
pg.init()


def main():
    screen = maze.GameBoard()
    ui = screen.lab_struct()
    screen.draw_objects()
    hero = player.McGyver(screen)

    pg.display.flip()

    while True:
        ev = pg.event.wait()
        key_pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if ev.type == pg.QUIT or key_pressed[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
            break
        elif ev.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            hero.del_mac()
            hero.update_mac(ev.key, ui)
            hero.show_mac()

        pg.display.flip()
```

here is the maze file

```
import pygame as pg
from random import sample
from design import constants as cst


class GameBoard(list):

    def __init__(self):
        self.master = pg.display.set_mode((cst.WINSIZE, cst.WINSIZE + 55))
        self.title = pg.display.set_caption(cst.GAME_TITLE)
        self.icon = pg.image.load(cst.MACGYVER_PIC)
        pg.display.set_icon(self.icon)

        self.wall = pg.image.load(cst.FULLWALL_PIC).convert_alpha()
        self.guard = pg.image.load(cst.GUARDIAN_PIC).convert_alpha()
        self.bkg = pg.image.load(cst.BKG_PIC).convert_alpha()
        self.itempic = (pg.image.load(cst.NEEDLE_PIC).convert_alpha(),
                        pg.image.load(cst.PIPE_PIC).convert_alpha(),
                        pg.image.load(cst.ETHER_PIC).convert_alpha())

        pg.key.set_repeat(200, 200)

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def lab_struct(self):
        with open('design/labyrinth') as maze:
            maze = ''.join(maze.read().splitlines())

            self.gdpos = divmod(maze.find('G'), 15)
            #self.extend([self.gdpos])

            self.extend([divmod(idx, 15) for idx, value in enumerate(maze)
                        if value == '0'])

            self.itempos = sample(self[1:], 3)

    def draw_objects(self):
        self.master.blit(self.wall, (0, 0))

        gdy, gdx = self.gdpos
        self.master.blit(self.guard, (gdx * 50, gdy * 50))

        for y, x in self:
            self.master.blit(self.bkg, (x * 50, y * 50),
                             (x * 50, y * 50, 50, 50))

        for it, (y, x) in zip(self.itempic, self.itempos):
            self.master.blit(it, (x * 50, y * 50))
```

here is the player file

```
import pygame as pg
from design import constants as cst


class McGyver(object):

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.bkg = pg.image.load(cst.BKG_PIC).convert_alpha()
        self.macpic = pg.image.load(cst.MACGYVER_PIC).convert_alpha()
        self.macpos = (0, 0)

        self.screen = screen
        self.screen.master.blit(self.macpic, self.macpos)

        self.arrows = {pg.K_UP: (-1, 0),
                       pg.K_DOWN: (1, 0),
                       pg.K_LEFT: (0, -1),
                       pg.K_RIGHT: (0, 1)}

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def del_mac(self):
        y, x = self.macpos
        self.screen.master.blit(self.bkg, (x * 50, y * 50),
                                (x * 50, y * 50, 50, 50))

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def update_mac(self, key, maze):
        y, x = self.macpos

        self.maze = maze
        offy, offx = self.arrows.get(key, (0, 0))
        if (y + offy, x + offx) in self.maze:
            self.macpos = (y + offy, x + offx)

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def show_mac(self):
        y, x = self.macpos
        self.screen.master.blit(self.macpic, (x * 50, y * 50))
```

I would like to use [maze] in [lab_struct] for [mac_update] function but i have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/game.py", line 44, in main
    hero.update_mac(ev.key, ui)
  File "/home/user/objects/player.py", line 36, in update_mac
    if (y + offy, x + offx) in self.maze:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: apparently, your `ui` variable is `None`. Could you print its value and see if this is the case?

Comment: ... `def lab_struct(self):` has to `return maze`

Comment: Since you're accepting maze as an argument (`update_mac(self, key, maze)`), that should probably be ` ... in maze`, not `in self.maze`?

Comment: Correct, it's None..

Comment: @Rabbid76 : Ok i do it now

Comment: New issue ```if (y + offy, x + offx) in maze:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple``` :)

Comment: simply use `print(..)` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variable - or learn how to use debuger. Error shows that you have string in `maze` but it seems you expect dictonary or list.

Comment: BTW: there is no need to add postfix `_mac` and `_object` to funciton's name - it is much easier to have the same names `draw`, `update`, etc in all classes and then you can keep different classes on list and use `for`-loop to execute `draw` on every element on list You can also keep items in `pygame.sprite.Group` and then you can execute `draw` without `for`-loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all so much.. I can work with all your tips

Answer (score 1):

If it cans help anyone, I found the solution after many tests.. thank to @Rabbid76.. for the way to reflexion and @furas for the way to debug :)

`def lab_struct(self):` has to `return self` not `return maze` because `maze` is a file with string and I wanted a tuple for position.. I don't wanted to read the maze file like I said (my mistake) but I wanted to use the full function..

Many thanks